# Determining the exact value of trigonometric functions using tan

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Use the special triangles to give exact 
solutions where possible. Find all values of x such that $0 \le x \le 2\pi$.

The question I have is

$\tan^2x=1$.

What I have done so far (it appears that there are two ways you could go about this) is I subtracted $1$ from both sides to get $\tan^2x-1=0$ and then factored it to $(\tan x-1)(\tan x+1)=0$. Just like finding the zeroes of a function I then must isolate for $x$ using $\tan x-1=0$ and $\tan x+1=0$.  However I am not certain about finding the acute angle for tangent ratios.  (I can use tan=opposite/adjacent to help).  When I draw the special triangle, I am not sure about what the next steps should be.

Comment: See these two pages: [1](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/att2/ltri45.htm) and [2](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/att2/ltri30.htm)

Comment: $$\tan(x)=1 \iff x=\frac\pi4 \pmod\pi$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Your calculations are correct and you found $\tan x=1$ or $\tan x=-1$. Now look at the figure where you see the corresponding values for x.

[image]

I have added some other arc to my figure, so you can better understand how the solution depends from the interval for $x$.

You can see that $\tan x=1$ for two angles that you can indicate as $x= \pi/4$ or $x= 5\pi/4$ if your interval is $0 \le x < 2\pi$ , or as $x=\pi/4$ or $x=-3\pi/4$ if your interval is $-\pi \le x < \pi$. And you can do the same for $\tan x = -1$ (you see the angles?).

These different possibilities reflect the fact that angles are defined ''modulo $2\pi$'', i.e. two angles that differs for $2\pi$ are the ''same'': so $ 5\pi/4=2\pi-\pi/4=0-\pi/4=-\pi/4$.

Comment: So for tanx=-1 the related acute angle is -pi/4 and tanx=1 is pi/4?  When I punch this into my calculator I also get these values, but I am not sure if using the calculator is the right method to find the answer.  However I must ask, why is tanx=-1 in quadrant 4?  In quadrants 1 and 3 tangent is positive while in quadrants 2 and 4 make tan negative.  I think there is something i am misunderstanding here, but thankyou for the visual, this helps a lot.

Comment: excuse me for adding another question in here.   But so then for this question there are two related acute angles? Because in questions we have dealt with in class, after finding the equations, you replace x for alpha  and then look for which quadrant the original ratio comes from (if it is positive or negative) which gives you your value of x.

Comment: But this question has two related acute angles? In all quadratic trig. functions I've done, one of the equations became "inadmissable" due to the domain and other reasons.  I don't know how to do a question with two.  Or perhaps there is something I am missing here?

Comment: I' have added something to my answer. I hope this will be helpful.